# Two queries return different data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running two queries according to me both should return same result, but i think i am missing something

```
SELECT "id", "email", "first_name", "last_name", locale
FROM "users" AS "users"
WHERE (
    EXISTS (
            SELECT cf.field_value, ucf.field_value
            FROM custom_fields cf
            LEFT JOIN users_custom_fields ucf ON cf."id" = ucf.custom_field_id
            WHERE cf."id" = 272 AND
            ((
                cf.field_value = 'true') OR
            (
                ucf.user_id = users.id AND ucf.field_value = 'true'))
    ))
```

it returns  record

```
SELECT users.id, cf.field_value, ucf.field_value, ucf.user_id
FROM users
Join custom_fields cf on cf.user_id = users.id
LEFT join users_custom_fields ucf on ucf.custom_field_id = cf."id"
WHERE cf."id" = 272 AND
              ((
                cf.field_value = 'true') OR
              (ucf.user_id = users.id AND ucf.field_value = 'true'))
```

and it doesn't return anything, is there any difference between these two?

Comment: Yes, those queries are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second query you also join custom_fields table with `cf.user_id = users.id`. first query does not have this.

With adding `cf.user_id = users.id`, your first query equal the second.

```
SELECT "id", "email", "first_name", "last_name", locale FROM "users" AS "users" WHERE (
    EXISTS (
    SELECT cf.field_value, ucf.field_value
            FROM custom_fields cf
                LEFT JOIN users_custom_fields ucf ON cf."id" = ucf.custom_field_id
            WHERE cf."id" = 272 
                AND cf.user_id = users.id
                AND (( cf.field_value = 'true') OR
             ( ucf.user_id = users.id AND ucf.field_value = 'true'))
    ))
```

Comment: first query also have `ucf.user_id = users.id`

Comment: I do not mention the `ucf`, the problem at `cf` join.

Comment: If i add `LEFT Join custom_fields cf on cf.user_id = users.id`, does this make difference?

Comment: no, because `cf."id"` column using with users_custom_fields table. if cf returns nothing users_custom_fields also return nothing.